# Inverse the spline interpolation SciPy

Tags: python, math, scipy, interpolation, spline

I have an array of X and Y data, and I also have a spline that outputs Y values based on X values.
I need to get a spline that will perform the reverse operation, i.e. output the X value over the Y value.
(`interpolate.splrep(y, x, s=0)` do not suggest)

```
def f(x):
    return math.sin(x)

def compare_func(func, a, b, eps):
    x_for_plot = list(np.arange(a, b, eps / 10))
    x = list(np.arange(a, b, eps))

    y_for_plot = [func(i) for i in x_for_plot]
    y = [func(i) for i in x]

    plt.plot(x_for_plot, y_for_plot, label='Orig')
    plt.scatter(x, y, label='Points', color='blue')

    spline = interpolate.splrep(x, y, s=0)

    y_interpolated = interpolate.splev(x_for_plot, spline, der=0)

    spline_inv = ???

    x_calc = interpolate.splev(y_interpolated, spline_inv, der=0)

    print(x_calc)
    #x_calc and x_for_plot must be equal

    plt.plot(x_for_plot, y_interpolated, label='Interpolated')

    plt.xlabel('X')
    plt.ylabel('Y')
    plt.legend()
    plt.show()

compare_func(f, -3, 3, 0.5)
```

Comment: The data might not support inversion

Comment: Well, a spline function might not be 1 to 1, i.e. there might be multiple x's which yield the same y. That's not the end of the world, though. You could just let it be and look for multiple solutions of y = S(x) where S is your spline function, and by looking, I mean solving y - S(x) = 0 via bisection or your favorite library function. Maybe make a grid of points and look for one solution per interval; obviously the result is limited by the maximum interval length.

Comment: Another approach is to construct a so-called monotone spline, which by construction is nondecreasing or nonincreasing between support points. Then you just have to search between local extrema of the data points. If you go down that road, it seems like you should be able to take each subsequence of points between local extrema and reverse the roles of x and y, i.e., construct a spline x = S(y), and then directly evaluate S(y) instead of solving y - S(x) = 0. I haven't tried it.